# Как правильно использовать Nine-patch?

Tags: java, android

Можете обьяснить для чего нужен этот формат? Я так понимаю он сделан для оптимизации `png` картинок при маштабировании...

Тогда 2 вопроса,

- почему все картинки не используются по умолчанию сразу в этом формате
  если это так удобно?
- Почему не использовать `svg` формат в таком случае?

Просто я сегодня почитал про этот формат и пытаюсь понять где я могу его использовать в своем проекте и не могу придумать... У меня и так все картинки нормально смотрятся а если нужно, что то маштабируемое я использую `svg`.

Я думал, может это уже устаревший формат? Так как те статьи которые нашел все от 2011-2013 года... Может он уже не используется?

Помогите разобраться))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nine-patch (9-patch) - специальный формат, который позволяет указать области растяжения (левый и верхний край) и размещения контента на изображении (правый и нижний край). Этот формат не используется для оптимизации, напротив, с его применением требуется проводить больше вычислений и использовать его без надобности (не по прямому применению) нет никакого смысла.

[image: scrn1]

Используется этот формат, в основном, для графически сложных бэкграундов у виджетов, когда итоговый размер виджета может изменяться, либо его относительные размеры (пропорции) могут изменяться. Например, кнопки.

Предположим нам требуется задать для кнопки такой вид:

[image: scrn2]

Такое проще нарисовать в растре, чем в векторном формате или с помощью примитивов, но появиться проблема, что при изменении относительных размеров, (например, длина в 5 раз больше ширины), что для кнопки естественно, ведь она может быть маленькой, а может быть на всю ширину экрана и при этом узкой, изображение будет искажено и получится такой ужас:

[image: scrn3]

Естественно, это никуда не годится и тут на помощь приходит 9-patch - задаем этому фону области растяжения, в которых нет изображения, которое может исказиться при растяжении, здесь это линии контура  (на скриншоте зеленая область) и  область контента, чтобы текст в кнопке не перекрывался и не совмещался с контурами изображения - на скриншоте фиолетовая область (текст будет размещаться только в пределах этой области):

[image: scrn4]

Теперь наша кнопка всегда будет иметь геометрически правильные пропорции, независимо от пропорций и размеров виджета, а текст внутри нее никогда не будет выходить за пределы отведенной ему зоны, наезжая на орнамент:

[image: scrn5]

Сделать такое любыми другими способами либо невозможно, либо весьма затруднительно, включая формат SVG, который масштабируется только пропорционально.

Данный формат не является устаревшим и при необходимости используется и, например, в современной библиотеке Google - AppCompat. Так, фон виджета `Spinner` (белый треугольник направленный вниз справа) выполнен в 9-patch - файл [*abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png*](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png) или индикатор табов - файл [abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png) - сделать такие, внешне простые фоны в `Shape` было бы сложнее и использование 9-patch оправдано. Необходимо так же обратить внимание на их размер - файлы очень маленькие (буквально несколько пикселей) и содержат только необходимое изображение, все остальное добавляется областями растяжения. Это позволяет несколько уменьшить объем результирующего APK.

Стоит заметить, что современные требования к дизайну идут в сторону упрощения внешнего вида виджетов - простые формы, примитивные контуры и в настоящее время эту же проблему обычно решают с помощью графических примитивов (класса `Shape` или эквивалента в xml-разметке) - они отлично масштабируются, включая искажение пропорций, легче для процессора и предпочтение формату 9-patch стоит отдавать только в случае, когда с помощью `Shape` нарисовать желаемый вид невозможно, либо затруднительно.

PS: Картинки взял в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/113623/), там же тема раскрыта несколько полнее.