# искажение пропорций изображения на кнопке

Tags: java, android, xml

есть такой код

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/endLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/restartButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/restartButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/joke_button_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_share_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

получаем такую вот штуку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать, чтобы изображение на кнопке не искажалось?

Comment: Чтобы не искажалось, ImageButton должна стать квадратной - либо выше кнопки слева, либо уже по ширине (не до конца экрана), либо на прямоугольном виджете, часть без изображения будет визуально  невидима. Какой из вариантов вам нужен?

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton - это потомок ImageView, значит пропорции сохраняются также:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы пропорции изображения не искажались, виджет должен иметь размеры изображения (для более сложных случаев [есть 9-patch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532047/177345))

Самое логичное решение - даем `ImageButton` размеры изображенияи оба виджета  центруем по вертикали:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/endLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/restartButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/restartButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/joke_button_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_share_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Будет кнопка с изображением слева, оставшееся место в контейнере будет занимать кнопка с надписью. Отступы между виджетами и от границ контейнера задаются атрибутами `margin`