# Background текста в андроид

Tags: android, textview, background

Здраствуйте..
Есть такой вопрос:
Есть текстовый виджет...

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Message text..."
    android:background="@drawable/bg_message"/>
```

Хочю установить в качастве фона для текста (именно для текста а не для всего екрана!) изображение..(пузырь)
Как в сообщениях типа ВК, WachApp.. 
Но в моем варианте кода иконка пузыря отображается как обычная картинка под текстом...
Как сделать так чтоб иконка пузыря была только под текстом и ростягивалась коректно, на вся ширину и длину текста..?

Comment: Вам нужен ninepatch - картинка будет растягиваться так, как нужно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532047/177345

Comment: Спасибо все получилось...